# Create, implement and debug a Timer Job

Tags: 2010

I tried to create a timer job using this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx

But in that first code the Globals does not exist on the context, I assume it might exist in the SPJobDefinition, but as its another version, it might be deprecated?

Does this article fully applies to sharepoint 2010?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should work with no issues in SP2010 also.

Are you talking about the object of Static class Globals? may be you can look into this post by Andrew Connell's post over time job here:
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx

Comment: yes I was talking about those globals, btw the article I posted is also from andrw O connells, but am I missing some reference so that it compiles?